# Use Azure Durable Function TaskHub name set from Azure App Configuration

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions, azure-app-configuration

Is it possible to set the TaskHub name for an Azure Durable Function from a value stored in the Azure App Configuration Service? My `host.json` file is:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "durableTask": {
            "hubName": "%TaskHubName%"
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm trying out using a `binder` in my Orchestration client:

```
[FunctionName("Test_HttpStart")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get")] HttpRequestMessage req,
    IBinder binder)
{
    var starter = await binder.BindAsync<IDurableOrchestrationClient>(
        new DurableClientAttribute { TaskHub = Configuration["TaskHubName"] });
```

This works when I have `TaskHubName` defined in `local.settings.json`:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
        "TaskHubName": "TestTaskHubName"
}
```

But when I remove it from `local.settings.json` and instead retrieve this value from Azure App Configuration:

```
Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
    {
        _ = options.Connect(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("app-configuration-connection-string"))
            .Select(@"TaskHubName");
    })
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

I receive the error:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask: Task hub name '%TaskHubName%' should contain only alphanumeric characters, start with a letter, and have length between 3 and 45. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Invalid container name. Check MSDN for more information about valid container naming.

So even though I can see the value from Azure App Configuration is pulled down and exists in the application's configuration it doesn't appear like it is being used. Is it possible to use a value from Azure App Configuration as the Durable Function's TaskHub name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The runtime binding should work but the error is likely coming from the startup sequence, which fetches the value from `host.json` which is used for the rest of the functionality like [internal queue triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-perf-and-scale#internal-queue-triggers).

Unfortunately, AFAIK there isn't a way to work around this now.

You could however up vote this [feature request to support app configuration references](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/920545-azure-app-configuration/suggestions/39505483-app-config-reference) that should support this scenario.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I'll mark your response as answered until it this is possible.

Comment: upvote feature reference link is broken