# Azure Durable Functions: passing storage connection string based on tenant id, how to do this

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I'm trying to create a durable function that takes a different connection string based on the tenant that is initiating the durable function.

The approach I've been trying to figure out uses the built-in attribute parameters but I haven't found a way to dynamically pass in the connection string.  That code looks like

```
    [FunctionName("Function1_HttpStart2")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart2(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
    [DurableClient(ConnectionName = x)] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
    ILogger log)
    {
```

Is there a way to pass variable "x" into the attribute? Or is there another way to create the IDurableOrchestrationClient bound to the connection?

I looked at newing up a DurableOrchestrationClient using the extensions package but it doesn't recognize that type.  So, I went back to see if passing data into the attribute would work.

So far nothing has worked.

Appreciate the assistance

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [implementation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/blob/8b956bef90fffc5cbc01ed8025ba7a4d12c7c83b/src/WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask/WebJobsConnectionInfoProvider.cs#L28), looks like the `ConnectionName` is the only option.

You could have to create app setting entries for each tenant you have or I suppose a better solution would be to setup a [custom configuration source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#customizing-configuration-sources) like [Azure App Configuration to store various connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-azure-functions-csharp?tabs=in-process).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I haven't confirmed if this approach using app configuration works now, but it wasn't supported some time ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62717878/use-azure-durable-function-taskhub-name-set-from-azure-app-configuration

Comment: I'll see if It works now